# Is it possible to use Azure mobile service with .net backend and clinet in Cordova ionic front end?t

Tags: cordova, azure, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I wanted to know is anyone got success in consuming Azure mobile service developed in .net backend and consumed with Cordova Ionic frontend application ?

Comment: I certainly see no reason that this isn't possible, it is all designed with well documented standards. Could you explain the actual problem you're having we might be able to help you find the problem easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally possible!

Azure Mobile Services can respond to any client of wherever platform it is made.

Cordova ( with Ionic or not ) uses HTTP request to stabilish communication with it's backend, and Azure Mobile Services is no more than a RESTful API host, waiting for HTTP requests.

So, be relaxed, because is that why this service was made for. :)